# Regarding the GradientTextView

Tags: android

I got this link which has library to use GradientTextView

https://github.com/koush/Widgets

But when I tried to compiled the sample it was giving me error of build xml

is there any proper procedure to add it in our project? am i missing something?

Comment: Which project would you like to import? Widgets or Widgets Sample?

Comment: Try to go to settings of the project, compiler and there setup compiler.

Comment: When I import the projects into Eclipse, there isn't any problem with them. Only if I try to open the buid.xml, it gives an error.

Comment: @mollybaba : I want to  import and of the one just to test.Then i will be implementing the same for my program. As in your above comment when I try to compile it, some build.xml error comes. I tried it by giving required path of sdk in  that build xml but still giving error

Comment: @koush : The one who has made this library is here on stackflow I got link from here somewhere only but I do not know how to contact him in Stackflow since I have less privelege.

Answer (score 1):

Its for dynamically creation of a textview.

The project you are referring to contain only class which extend textview if you want to use that pass the required parameters in class constructor.

Its not complete project its just a class.

Comment: I was trying to pass the required paramet in class constructor but I am noob on android so got confused when I had to pass defnStyle and Attr Set . I am not great at android ..just started . If any line or something to help me out will be appreciated